# Limitations of satellite radar for precipitation measurement?

Tags: meteorology, weather-satellites, radar

Companies like tomorrow.io are [promising](https://www.tomorrow.io/space/) satellite-based weather radar. However, I can easily imagine several flaws (especially in combination with the greater distance to storms than a ground-based radar):

- Limited power?
- Limited SNR?
- Potential interference?

It's unclear to me how realistic these potential flaws are; I give them solely as examples. My question is: excluding engineering/economic disadvantages, **are there physics-based disadvantages to having a space-based weather radar compared to a ground-based radar?**